# how can user chat in whatsapp app with his/her input mobile number in html form?

Tags: php, html

```
<?php

require_once('./database.php');

if(isset($_REQUEST['submit1']))
{
    $number = $_REQUEST['whatsappnumber'];
    $code   = $_REQUEST['countorycode'];
    $sql = "INSERT INTO whatsapp (whatsappnumber,countorycode) VALUES ('$number','$code')";

    if($affected_row = $conn->exec($sql))
    {
        $sq = "SELECT * FROM whatsapp";
        $res = $conn -> query($sq);
        while($row = $res -> fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
        {
            $i = $row['whatsappnumber'];
            $j = $row['countorycode'];

            $url = 'https://wa.me/'.$j.$i.'?text=helloworld';
            header('Location: ' . $url);

        }
    }

    else
    {
       echo 'please try again';
    }


}
else
{

    echo 'data not inserted';
}



?>
```

I want to add a form in my html page where user enter any whatsapp number, after clicking submit, user is directed to whatsapp app, opening that particular chat which is entered by a user by some default text to send.olny user has to click send button and the default text is sent.a simple form is to be created with input of mobile number by a user.i am new in web developing.how can i do this?

i have tried to create form where mobile number is given by user and stored to database. but the problem is how to get that mobile number from database and redirect to whatsapp app with that particular number.
Thankss

Comment: Have a read on this [PHP PDO Prepared Statements Tutorial to Prevent SQL Injection](https://websitebeaver.com/php-pdo-prepared-statements-to-prevent-sql-injection)

Comment: Also what in the world is the purpose of your while loop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably want something like this: a URL to `https://wa.me/whatsappphonenumber?text=urlencodedtext`, so if your phone number is `0987654321` and your message is `Hello world` your URL would look like this: `https://wa.me/0987654321?text=Hello%20world`, and if users click this link it will open Whatsapp / Whatsapp Web to send a message to you with the prefilled message.

Comment: yes, exactly like this..olny but here phone number is user input..user will input any number.

Comment: So is your question answered then, or do you need help with using the phone number in the link?

Comment: i need help with using the phone number in link..how can i add the user inpur number to the link?

Comment: Can you show the code you use now for the form and form processing?

Comment: `        <form action="whatsapp.php" method="post">
        
        <input type="number" name="whatsappnumber" placeholder="10 digit number" class="input1">
        <button  class="btn" name="submit1" type="submit"><i class="fa fa-whatsapp inputicon" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>
       </form>`

Comment: @RahulSingh and what is in whatapp.php?

Comment: thanks for your help...finally i have done any how!!  thanks

Comment: @RahulSingh please mark the question as answered if it is solved, and maybe edit the post with the solution you used, so others can benefit from your question aswell.